# I get MongoClient Connection error response when loading a GET request with Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

Whenever I tried fetching my data through GET request on Postman, I get this  MongoDB Atlas error of connection which does not always happen with POST request. I just started this journey. Your kind help will be so much appreciated.

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const router = express.Router();
const Product = require('../model/product');

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    Product.find()
    .exec()
    .then(docs=>{
        console.log(docs);
        res.status(200).json(docs);
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({error:err}); 

    }); 
});  




router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {


    const product = new Product({
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price
    });

    product.save().then(result=>{
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(err=> console.log(err)); 




    res.status(200).json({
        message:'Products Added!!! ',
        createdProduct: product
    });
});
```

I always get this Error:

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to.
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you check the documentation https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Mongoose queries are not promises. instead use async/await

```
router.get("/", async (req,res)=>{
   const docs=await Product.find().sort("name")
   res.status(200).send(docs)
})
```

Comment: Thank you Yilmaz. I had to switch from Atlas to the local Mongodb.exe and everything is working out fine sir. I really appreciate you for this